# Block-unblock or create-uncreate reg keys prevent rewriting or accidental or deliberate deletion, using the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, windows-registry, batch-file

I have [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/1098543/block-a-registry-key-to-prevent-rewriting-or-deleting-accidentally-or-intentiona) to block registry keys and prevent accidental or deliberate deletion or rewriting, either by a user or by malware

example of keys:

```
"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cmd.exe"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\cmd.exe"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\ComSpec"
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PATHEXT"
```

etc.

Protect keys: Create a c:\protect.txt with this content:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cmd.exe [2 19] 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\cmd.exe [2 19]
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\ComSpec [2 19]
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PATHEXT [2 19]
```

etc

And execute command

```
regini c:\block.txt
```

> **Question:** **How I can reverse these changes?**
>
> **Important Note:** What I want is a solution to automate the process with batch (a ".bat" to block and a ".bat" to reverse/restore original permission).. but first read or export keys permission to restore

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How I can reverse these changes?

You can reverse the changes by setting the permission entry is set to `[1 17]` which is Administrators Full Access and SYSTEM Full Access.

1. Create a file (for example `unblock.txt`) with the following contents:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cmd.exe [1 17] 
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\cmd.exe [1 17]
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\ComSpec [1 17]
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment\PATHEXT [1 17]
   ```
2. Execute the `unblock.txt` script using the following command, run from an elevated (Administrator) `cmd` shell:

   ```
   regini unblock.txt
   ```

Notes:

- The `regini` command must be run from an elevated (Administrator) `cmd` shell, otherwise it will fail (an no error will be displayed).

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [regini](http://ss64.com/nt/regini.html) - Change Registry Permissions.
- [How to: Use a Script to Change Registry Permissions from the Command Line](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/245031)

Comment: When I create a new registry key, it is created without administrative permissions (only special permits). In the case of existing keys (to avoid complicating the batch script), what I do is determine which permissions have these keys when you originally and restoration, rather than put to 1-17 key, I put the number corresponding to the original value of permits. Thanks

Comment: I would like to know the key permissions via cmd.exe

Comment: @brianc You need to find a copy of `regdmp`. Unfortunately `regdmp` is no longer downloadable from Microsoft.

Comment: Maybe with [this](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/examples/locking-and-unlocking-the-registry-with-setacl-exe/) i solved the problem.. testing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will reverse these changes the same way - only numbers at the end of every row will be different.

So please, plan good and carefully! (I always advise everyone to take pen and draw design on sheet of paper)

1) when you are making blocking, you must left at least one user/group with suficient, not blocked rights (full rights e.g.)

2) when you are making unblocking, you must doing it as that user/group, who have right to change those registry keys

If you want to know original rights (their numbers), you can use `regdmp` before any changes, you make.

Comment: Unfortunately `regdmp` is no longer downloadable from Microsoft.